Using Lookup activity output as source for activities inside ForEach loop in ADF
I need to use the output of the lookup as the source of for example pipeline inside ForEach loop. So 1. I have an excel as a source for the lookup with one column 'code'. each row in the column has codes in format "123", "321", "231"....
2. Now I need to iterate over every row with the ForEach loop to insert the output of the current lookup to the pipeline withing the ForEach loop
3. Inside the pipeline I use the lookup output in request body of copy activity to call API.
I can't figure out how to do this with the parameters. I need the source to change to a new row dunamically over every ForEach iteration.
pipeline
